# if I delete private/var/folders/zz to free up space will it cause any problem?

Tags: macos, mojave, storage

I am very new to mac. I want to upgrade to the latest version of mac but there is not enough space in my mac. After some digging, I found there is a folder called private that is taking more than 38GB of storage. I have given the screenshot below. But some forums on the internet say, I should not delete the private/var/folders. I am not sure what to do. I have no important data to lose. Now should i delete this folder? If yes what is the correct way to delete these huge files?

[image: Found this with the help of omnidisk app]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a Safe Boot (press the Shift Key when you boot) and verify if you get free space after doing a normal reboot.
The Safe boot clean system cache files.

Comment: happy for you. ;-)